# strconv.ParseFloat turning values to 0 when it shouldn't

Tags: parsing, go, floating-point, gccgo

I have the following code:

```
buffer := make([]byte, 256)
conn.Read(buffer)

result:= string(buffer)
fmt.Println("Val:", result)

floatResult, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(result, 64)
fmt.Println("Val on float:", floatResult)
```

The output is the following:

```
Val: 40.385167
Val on float: 0
```

This seems the correct way to parse string into `float64`'s, is there something i'm missing?

Comment: What was `_` - did `strconv.ParseFloat` return an error?

Comment: @wim oh yes: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "-0.000000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x
00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 .......... invalid syntax

Comment: Solved it by changing the byte array size to match my results, if i had more than that it would append giant amounts of '\x00...'

Comment: Yeah, you should always check errors in Go; sometimes it's convenient to skip it if you just want to quick test something, but if it's not working then that's the first thing to check :-) And in "real" production code you should really always check errors.

Comment: 1) the application ignores the number of bytes read and error from the connection. Because there's no guarantee that Read fills the buffer (and it doesn't here), the count of bytes should always be used.  2) Assuming that this is a TCP connection, there's no guarantee that all of the bytes in the number are slurped up a single call to Read. The application needs to implement some sort of message framing if multiple values are sent or read to EOF if  single value is sent.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new slice with `len` equals read bytes (look at [Reader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader))

```
buffer := make([]byte, 256)
i, _ := conn.Read(buffer) // i  number of read bytes 

result:= string(buffer[:i]) // create new slice with 'len' equals number of read bytes
fmt.Println("Val:", result)

floatResult, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(result, 64)
fmt.Println("Val on float:", floatResult)
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND (io.Reader stub)](https://play.golang.org/p/MGjrIRkSC6q)</kbd>